# How to shift string by some number of characters in linux

Tags: linux, string, bash, text

Is there a one liner that shifts all characters in a string by some `i` number. The input string can contain any ascii characters. It would be for a cypher.

For example, if `b` comes after `a` then `command 1 "ab"` returns `"bc"`, `command 3 "ab"` returns `"de"`. It should work with any ascii character not just with letters.

Comment: Please specify the language you use (with a tag) and add the code you tried (in your question).

Answer (score 0):

The command you want is called caesar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Perl`:

```
 echo -n bbb | perl -F'' -ane 'foreach(@F){$_++; printf "$_"}END{print "\n"}'
 ccc
```

If you need shift a N chars (in the case below `4`):

```
echo -n bbb | perl -F'' -ane 'foreach(@F){ $a=ord($_); $a+=4; print chr($a)} END{print "\n"}'
fff
```

Shifting to negative value:

```
echo -n bbb | perl -F'' -ane 'foreach(@F){ $a=ord($_); $a-=1; print chr($a)} END{print "\n"}'
aaa
```

Comment: is there a way to do a negative number, shift by -1

Answer (score 0):

this gawk command gives you new sequence with `ascii code+1`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="";s=2;for(n=0;n<=127;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n}
          {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%c",(ord[$i]+s)%127)}7'
```

test with string shifted with step `2`:

```
kent$  echo "xyab+123"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="";s=2;for(n=0;n<=127;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=sprintf("%c",(ord[$i]+s)%127)}7' 
z{cd-345
```

you just need pass the `s` as variable, to define shift step.

Comment: if you read my answer, you see in example I have `+-{123456`, which are not letters. If you read the codes, you 'll see it works for ascii code  `0-127`. @siamii